# Vos modifications de code PHP ont été annulées en raison d’une erreur sur la ligne 296 syntax error, unexpected '=', expecting ')'

Tags: php, wordpress

I copied this php code from internet in wp website and i didn't how to solve this error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8faH.png

Comment: This question should be at least edited to contain an english title als english is the lingua franca for SO. Imo it should be closed as it clearly lacks clarity and details

Answer (score 1):

Those are associative arrays. See: https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

How to fix your code:

instead of `=` its should be `=>` inside the array function.

Comment: yes, i replaced = with => and it worked

Comment: Maybe set this answer as the accepted answer/solution so others know your problem is solved?